# Delete specific XML elements after finding specific test condition within the element start/end tag

Tags: xml, shell, awk, sed

I'm looking to create a quick shell script (HP-UX system) to remove XML tags based on a simple test condition. I can't use XML aware tools like 'xmlstarlet' as these are not available on my production systems for a number of reasons. I do realise these are the right way to go, but I've no choice in the matter.

Consider the two XML elements below relating to two devices. When a device is out-of-comms there will be no StationId and no HardwareInv, tags differ with `<..../>` at end. When a device is in comms, the StationId is present and HardwareInv content available, the start/end tags are complete, i.e. `</....>` at end.

I would like to find and remove devices out-of-comms by searching for `<StationId/>` and/or `<HardwareInv/>` and if found, completely delete all content between the associated DeviceA tags, including the DeviceA tags themselves leaving no blank line behind.

I have tried a few things with varying results using 'sed' in particular, but nothing 100% successful. Your help is greatly appreciated.

This is the input XML file:

```
<DeviceA>
  <PhysicalAdd>10.10.10.69</PhysicalAdd>
  <NEId>0000-Test-06</NEId>
  <StationId/>

  *** MORE CONTENT REMOVED ***

  <HardwareInv/>
</DeviceA>
<DeviceA>
  <PhysicalAdd>10.10.10.109</PhysicalAdd>
  <NEId>0000-Test-13</NEId>
  <StationId>Bravo-01</StationId>

  *** MORE CONTENT REMOVED ***

  <HardwareInv>
    <Unit>
      <UnitId>1</UnitId>
      <SerialNumber>1389A</SerialNumber>
    </Unit>
  </HardwareInv>
</DeviceA>
```

The expected output:

```
<DeviceA>
  <PhysicalAdd>10.10.10.109</PhysicalAdd>
  <NEId>0000-Test-13</NEId>
  <StationId>Bravo-01</StationId>

  *** MORE CONTENT REMOVED ***

  <HardwareInv>
    <Unit>
      <UnitId>1</UnitId>
      <SerialNumber>1389A</SerialNumber>
    </Unit>
  </HardwareInv>
</DeviceA>
```

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks for input, will update the post. It is part of a large file and is to be used as input. The expected output is explained in the explanation but will update post any way.

Comment: @EdMorton, Unfortunately no GNU awk available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script is simple enough to work with any version of awk:

```
awk '
/<DeviceA>/          { found = 0; tosave = 1; save = "" }
/<HardwareInv\/>/ || /<StationId\/>/        { found = 1 }
/<DeviceA>/,/<\/DeviceA>/   { save = save $0 "\n" }
tosave==0            { print }
/<\/DeviceA>/        { if(!found)printf "%s",save; tosave = 0 }
'
```

It detects the starting tag and sets two booleans to false, 0, and true, 1, and clears out a string variable `save`.
When the empty tags are found, the `found` boolean is set true.
All lines between the start and end tag of the group to be removed are accumulated in the string variable, with a newline between them.

If not saving lines, then print them. When the end tag is matched,
if the empty tags were not found, print the saved group, and stop saving.

There is some redundancy in the code, but it is to keep it simple. Obviously, this handles only data in the format you gave, and is not for any xml.

Comment: I found an issue with POSIX awk (HP-UX system) which I've not come across before, it appears there is a 300 byte hard limit (this is the error: "awk: Format item %s cannot be longer than 3,000 bytes".
) when running script against the 'real' file. Obviously, the sample shown has missing content so its not apparent in the example given. I did manage to find that two of our HP-UX systems do have gawk after all and running as a gawk script, all worked like a dream (doesn't have the limitations of POSIX awk), so thank you for the solution!

Comment: Interesting. If the issue is just because `%s` is too long, the simple answer is to replace the `printf "%s",save` by `print substr(save,1,length(save)-1)`. I was only using it to delete the final newline, as print will add a final newline anyway.

Comment: Yep, that last suggestion worked with POSIX awk :-) fine, takes slightly longer to complete BUT works fine, again, big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It'd be briefer with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='</DeviceA>\\s*' -v ORS= '/<StationId>/{print $0 RT}' file
<DeviceA>
  <PhysicalAdd>10.10.10.109</PhysicalAdd>
  <NEId>0000-Test-13</NEId>
  <StationId>Bravo-01</StationId>

  *** MORE CONTENT REMOVED ***

  <HardwareInv>
    <Unit>
      <UnitId>1</UnitId>
      <SerialNumber>1389A</SerialNumber>
    </Unit>
  </HardwareInv>
</DeviceA>
```

but with any awk you just need to build up the record line by line first:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ rec = (rec=="" ? "" : rec ORS) $0 }
/<\/DeviceA>/ {
    if (rec ~ /<StationId>/) {
        print rec
    }
    rec = ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
<DeviceA>
  <PhysicalAdd>10.10.10.109</PhysicalAdd>
  <NEId>0000-Test-13</NEId>
  <StationId>Bravo-01</StationId>

  *** MORE CONTENT REMOVED ***

  <HardwareInv>
    <Unit>
      <UnitId>1</UnitId>
      <SerialNumber>1389A</SerialNumber>
    </Unit>
  </HardwareInv>
</DeviceA>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to provide a solution. As per comment in other solution, there was an issue with POSIX awk. I tried this solution but if did not generate any output, even when using gawk. I've yet to analyse why but the other solution did work, albeit using gawk.

Comment: Since you DO have GNU awk I added the GNU awk solution and I loosened up the text for the end of record to allow for trailing white space and replaced the printf with a print.

Comment: Yep, I agree, your solution works fine against the pasted content. I accept that the 'real' file which is 67 MB and growing has a lot more content and that any potential solution posted may fail as a result. I posted the part where I identified a 'change' that I could trap/look for. I created a larger script but just needed some assistance from someone with a bit more sed/awk knowledge than myself on this particular bit. many thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: Will test the new solution and respond ;-)

Comment: Sounds good. If you don't get any output this time then `<StationId>` must not exist in your input.

Comment: Perfect, works like a dream with 'gawk' (think you intended to put that in your GNU awk solution above as opposed to 'awk') . Many thanks!

Comment: Good. No, naming it `awk` isn't a mistake. Every `awk` on every UNIX box is some variation on a theme, no need to name them all on invocation, in many cases `awk` simply IS the name of  the variant on that box and in many cases they have no specific name other than simply `awk` (e.g. /usr/xpg4/bin/awk on Solaris is a specific awk version, just like GNU awk is). It's enough just to say "using GNU awk...".

Comment: Yep, but not on our HP-UX systems, it is 'gawk' otherwise you will invoke POSIX awk, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I understand but that's just something you have to deal with on your specific system. In others (e.g. cygwin) awk simply IS gawk. In others awk is mawk while in others awk is something else and you need to type mawk to get it. In others awk is nawk, and in others awk is oawk, and in others awk is tawk, and so on.... Also other awks and POSIX evolve so a feature that's gawk-specific one day becomes POSIX another (e.g. mawk is getting gensub()). So IMHO it's fine to just state "using GNU awk for <feature X>" and then call it as awk just like any other variant and let users take it from there.